# Fazer upload de arquivo com AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json, upload

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma simples de realizar um upload de arquivos via AJAX + JSON.

Se houver, qual seria?

Comment: Que linguagem existe no lado do servidor? Porquê JSON? i.e. referes-te ao JSON para uma função específica?

Comment: Há uma resposta deletada sugerindo este vídeo tutorial: [Upload com jQuery e barra de progresso](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x6Z60tNxRN0)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Você pode fazer uploads de arquivos utilizando o método `POST` porém deve incluir o [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) com a propriedade `enctype` definida como `multipart/form-data` para que seus arquivos sejam enviados na requisição.

Contudo, a formatação do envio não vai ser um JSON, mas sim no `enctype` que você definir no seu `FormData`, que dependendo da linguagem que você está utilizando no backend vai ter uma forma diferente de interpretar estes dados.

- **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**: é o enctype padrão, todos os valores de espaço são convertidos para "+" e caracteres não padrões são convertidos para representação ANSII HEX;
- **multipart/form-data**: nenhum caractere é convertido, mantendo os valores do formulário intactos, necessário para upload de arquivos;
- **text/plain**: apenas espaços são convertidos em "+";

Sendo essas as possibilidades, o que está sendo trafegado não é um JSON quando vamos comunicar enviando dados para o servidor. Esses dados são serializados para serem entregues dentro da área de data do método que você esta utilizando pra trafegar via HTTP(S) dentro dos formatos apresentados.

Durante o upload você pode capturar (nos browsers modernos) evento de progresso do upload, conforme no exemplo abaixo.

Exemplo utilizando **jQuery**

**Formulário**

```
<form id="formulario" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="campo1" value="hello" />
    <input type="text" name="campo2" value="world" />
    <input name="arquivo" type="file" />
    <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#formulario").submit(function() {
    var formData = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: window.location.pathname,
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data)
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        xhr: function() { // Custom XMLHttpRequest
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if (myXhr.upload) { // Avalia se tem suporte a propriedade upload
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function() {
                    /* faz alguma coisa durante o progresso do upload */
                }, false);
            }
            return myXhr;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: como faz para escolher a pasta onde o arquivo será enviado?

Comment: Detalhe muito importante, no I.E o `FormData` funciona somente a partir da versão 10 em diante

Comment: cara funcionou perfeitamente no meu sistema, vlw.

Comment: @GabrielGartz como eu poderia utilizar seu código para preencher uma tag progress no submit? `<progress id="progress" value="0"></progress>`

Comment: Mas se o FormData é envio via ajax/javascript, o enctype influencia?

Comment: @KarlZillner o `FormData` usa o enctype padrão como `multipart/form-data`, o código funcionará sem este estar definido no HTML, da forma que está escrito se o JavaScript não estiver ativo ou não for suportado, o formulário ainda vai funcionar para fazer o upload.

Answer (score 40):

Implementação simples do lado "client":

**HTML:**

```
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" />
<input type="button" id="btnEnviar" value="Enviar" />
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function () {

    var form;
    $('#fileUpload').change(function (event) {
        form = new FormData();
        form.append('fileUpload', event.target.files[0]); // para apenas 1 arquivo
        //var name = event.target.files[0].content.name; // para capturar o nome do arquivo com sua extenção
    });

    $('#btnEnviar').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'URL SERVER', // Url do lado server que vai receber o arquivo
            data: form,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                // utilizar o retorno
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Sugiro que você busque por tutorias mais completos na internet. Busque por ["file upload ajax"](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=file+upload+ajax&oq=file+upload+ajax&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i60j0l3.344j0j9&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) que o google vai te bombardear com diversos artigos, com implementações simples e complexas.

Comment: Cara, eu te amo, namoral kkkk

Answer (score 9):

Utilizo uma forma genérica na maioria das páginas que utilizo, tanto em formulários com upload de arquivos quanto formulários sem upload de arquivos.

```
$(form).on('submit', function () {
    var data;
    var contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    var processData = true;
    if ($(this).attr('enctype') == 'multipart/form-data') {
        data = new FormData($('.form-horizontal').get(0));//seleciona classe form-horizontal adicionada na tag form do html
        contentType = false;
        processData = false;
    } else {
        data = $(this).serialize();
    }
    $.ajax({
        data: data,
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        contentType: contentType,
        processData: processData,
        success: function (response) {
            //seu código após sucesso
        },
        error: function (exr, sender) {
                alert('Erro ao carregar pagina');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Uma solução simples de upload de múltiplos arquivos utilizando Ajax:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="file"  id="uploadArquivos" multiple>
```

**JAVASCRIPT - AJAX:**

```
var uploadArquivo = $("#uploadArquivos");

uploadArquivo.on('change', function(e) {
  files = e.target.files;
  var formData = new FormData(),
    file = [];

  $.each(files, function(key, val) {
    file[key] = val;
  });

  formData.append('file', file);

  $.ajax({
    url: 'urlDoArquivo',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: formData,
    type: 'post',
    success: function(data) {

    }
  });

});
```

Quando o usuário selecionar os arquivos ele criará um formData inserindo cada arquivo e seus detalhes e enviando para o arquivo da url do ajax, se for em php você poderá pegar este valor e mover para uma pasta assim:

**PHP:**

```
foreach ($_FILES as $value):
   move_uploaded_file($value['tmp_name'], '../temp/' . $value['name']);
endforeach;
```