# Qual a melhor forma de fazer upload de arquivos com Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

Poderia pegar um código na Internet colar aqui e tentar uma resposta mas prefiro que me ajudem com a lógica e programação de um script para upload de imagens em Ajax. Eu não sei como começar, sou iniciante mas conheço já algumas coisas de jQuery e Ajax. Nesse upload eu vou cadastrar 5 campos no banco de dados que são;

```
id, nome(md5), titulo, descricao, datacadastro
```

Comment: Acho interessante mostrar um pouco de esforço de pesquisa e pelo menos alguma tentativa de implementação. Veja [ask]

Comment: Eu tenho me esforçado pra aprender, pode ver nas minhas outras perguntas. Só não postei código desta vez porque tem tanta vertente que eu não queria começar errado.

Comment: Um lugar para começar: http://forum.codecall.net/topic/37937-php-upload-class/

Comment: Se você é iniciante, não recomendo fazer do zero a parte client-side. Tem muitos detalhes necessários para funcionar cross-browser (como fallback usando iframes), é melhor usar uma biblioteca pronta que já resolva essas coisas. Por exemplo: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Comment: Pesquise sobre plupupload é o melhor plugin que já encontrei...

Comment: O jQuery-File-Upload citado pelo @bfavaretto é realmente muito bom! Vide a quantidade de forks do projeto no github. Acho que vale a pena vê-lo funcionando na página de exemplo (http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) e ler a documentação no link já citado.

Comment: Se você não se sente confortável com jquery ou não quer usar o plugin http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ citado anteriormente, uma outra opção seria setar o target do form para um iframe.

Comment: Para resolver meu problema de upload de imagens, acabei usando o jQuery File Upload. Obrigado a todos que comentaram.

Comment: O ideal é você procurar exemplos que utilizem php para fazer o processo do upload, tem classes só pra isso.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uma dica é você fazer o upload separado do conteúdo.

Faça um comando com a linguagem de programação que irá usar, fazendo um INSERT para os dados como nome, titulo, etc.

Após feito o comando SQL para inserir apenas o conteúdo, faça uma página ou um bloco na mesma página com esse plug-in de upload via jQuery:

http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php

Nesse plug-in, ele faz upload multiplo usando PHP, jQuery e MySQL, além de ter muitas opções como especificar extensões permitidas, opção 'arrastar & soltar arquivos para upload', barra de progresso dos uploads, output de resposta do upload e etc.

Usei esse plug-in e não me arrependi, pois ajudou minha necessidade em 100%.

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma simples de fazer isso você encontra [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9704/fazer-upload-de-arquivo-com-ajax).

Acrescento apenas...

As bibliotecas e classes sugeridas são todas válidas e vai te mostrar 
"o caminho", mas se quiser tentar implementar por conta própria então comece fazendo sem Ajax.

Inicie pelo formulário, depois receba os dados (as imagens) pelo php, resolva a questão do DB e, por último, implemente o Ajax.

O link que eu passei deve te ajudar.