# Extrair informações de um vídeo no momento do upload

Tags: php, jquery, vídeo

Fazer o upload de um vídeo qualquer é a parte fácil, porém eu gostaria de explorar mais esse momento do upload. Eu gostaria de extrair algumas informações do vídeo no momento do upload. Essas informações seriam o tempo que o vídeo tem e a quantidade de MB dele. E gostaria também que no momento do upload essas informações extraídas preenchessem automaticamente os inputs referentes a essas informações.

O que eu quero na verdade é extrair as informações, seja em php, jquery ou qualquer outro tipo meio viável.

Breve exemplo :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Seria bom se você mostrasse o método que está usando para fazer o upload.

Comment: No momento posso dizer que não existe método nenhum, estou apenas utilizando um pouco de PHP pra pegar o arquivo e transferir o vídeo pra uma pasta. Quer que eu poste o código php?

Comment: Ivan no JavaScript está muito limitado. Quase tudo é proibido/bloqueado por razões de segurança. Acho que vai ter de fazer via PHP, e isso quer dizer "depois do upload".

Comment: @Sergio, pode ser também depois do upload, mas como eu posso extrair essas informações do vídeo com o php?

Comment: Nesse caso sugiro editar a pergunta, juntar essa possibilidade e juntar a tag PHP também

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Em javascript** isso é muito limitado por razões de segurança.

O tamanho sei ser possível através do `this.files[0].size` e o nome, através de `this.files[0].name` usado um event handler no jQuery. Depois para formatar para ser perceptível pode usar uma função como esta:

```
function humanFileSize(bytes, si) {
    var thresh = si ? 1000 : 1024;
    if(bytes < thresh) return bytes + ' B';
    var units = si ? ['kB','MB','GB','TB','PB','EB','ZB','YB'] : ['KiB','MiB','GiB','TiB','PiB','EiB','ZiB','YiB'];
    var u = -1;
    do {
        bytes /= thresh;
        ++u;
    } while(bytes >= thresh);
    return bytes.toFixed(1)+' '+units[u];
};
```

**Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/16jv4r89/1/**

**Em PHP** encontrei [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4847873/2256325) que sugere uma [biblioteca externa getID3](http://getid3.sourceforge.net/) que suporta formatos diferentes. Dando uma olhada na página suporta os formatos mais comuns.

Assim no PHP seria:

```
$getID3 = new getID3;
$file = $getID3->analyze($filename);
echo("Duration: ".$file['playtime_string'].
" / Dimensions: ".$file['video']['resolution_x']." wide by ".$file['video']['resolution_y']." tall".
" / Filesize: ".$file['filesize']." bytes<br />");
```

Comment: U're fast, man :) Encontrei a mesma resposta lá no SO... . . . .  @Ivan, estava pesquisando e tem material interessante aqui no site, tipo [Fazer upload de arquivo com ajax](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9704/201); tinha uma outra que era para capturar metadata de imagens antes do upload mas não estou achando.

Answer (score -1):

Pode sempre utilizar `print_r($_FILES["upload"])` para sacar as propriedades do ficheiro e depois utilizar o que deseja assim
ex pegar o tamanho que tem

```
echo $_FILES["upload"]["size"];
```

ou

```
$new_var = $_FILES["upload"];
echo $new_var["size"];
```

Comment: Isso só está disponível depois que o arquivo tiver sido enviado para o servidor. A pergunta é sobre como pegar a duração ou tamanho do arquivo do vídeo antes disso.