# Obter nome do arquivo no input file

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um input, onde quando eu clicar, quero que informe o nome do arquivo.

Tenho o seguinte código:

**HTML**

```
<div class="trabalheObs">Carregar Curr&iacute;culo</div>
<input style="display:none" type="file" class="margin-top-20 cp" id="curriculoForm" name="curriculoForm" value="" />
```

**CSS**

```
.trabalheObs {
        background-image: url("../imagens/curriculo.png");
        background-position: 420px center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        margin-top: 20px;
        width: 460px;
        height: 45px;
        border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 25px;
        text-indent: 23px;
        font-family:"roboto";
        font-weight: 300;
        font-style: italic;
        color: #999999;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(".trabalheObs").click(function () {
    $("#curriculoForm").click();
});
```

Se vocês notarem, coloquei uma **DIV** por cima, para mascarar o layout feio padrão de um **input**. Porém, gostaria que ele informasse o nome do arquivo selecionado, como fazer isso?

Quero que o nome do arquivo fique dentro da **div** `trabalheObs`

Comment: Relacionado/duplicado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38877/129

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voce pode obter o nome do arquivo selecionado obtendo o valor do campo.

Nesse caso especifico, usando o seguinte codigo:

```
var nomeDoArquivo = $("#curriculoForm").val(); // obtem o nome
$(".trabalheObs").html(nomeDoArquivo); // coloca o nome dentro da div

// ao clicar na div, dispara a acao do botao escondido
$(".trabalheObs").click(function(){
    $("#curriculoForm").click();
})
```

Comment: E como informo o nome dentro da **div** `trabalheObs`?

Comment: @FelipeStoker Editei a minha resposta. Veja se te ajuda.

Comment: O conteúdo da **div** fica igual? <div class="trabalheObs">Carregar Curr&iacute;culo</div>

Comment: @FelipeStoker Nao reparei que voce estava usando classe ao inves de ID. Editei minha resposta para usar classe.

Comment: Nem eu percebi, hehe. Seguinte, ele informou o nome dentro do **input**, só que deixei como `display:none`, precisaria que informasse dentro da **div**

Comment: O value inclui o caminho do arquivo, que muitos browsers não permitem acessar. No Chrome, por exemplo, seu código retorna `C:\fakepath\nome-do-arquivo.ext`.

Comment: Tem como eu informar esse valor dentro da **div**?

Comment: @FelipeStoker Nao sei se entendi direito, mas voce quer que ao clicar na div, abra a tela para escolher o arquivo? Se for isso, veja a edicao. Adicionei um evento de click na div que simula um click no botao de upload escondido.

Comment: Isso eu já havia feito. O que acontece, é que o `input` está escondido, com a `div` por cima. Eu queria que o nome do arquivo fosse informado dentro da `div` e não no `input`.

Answer (score 5):

Em JavaScript puro, é possível obter o nome do arquivo manipulando-se o objeto Input FileUpload, conforme exemplo abaixo:

```js
var div = document.getElementsByClassName("botaoArquivo")[0];
var input = document.getElementById("inputArquivo");

div.addEventListener("click", function(){
    input.click();
});
input.addEventListener("change", function(){
    var nome = "Não há arquivo selecionado. Selecionar arquivo...";
    if(input.files.length > 0) nome = input.files[0].name;
    div.innerHTML = nome;
});
```

```css
#inputArquivo { display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="botaoArquivo">Selecionar arquivo...</div>
<input type="file" id="inputArquivo">
```