# Pegar o nome de uma imagem por Php ou JS

Tags: php, javascript, arquivo

Bom, eu tenho um formulário no qual tem um `input` do `type ='file'`. Já vi em vários sites e exemplos de como fazer e todos que eu testo não funcionam. o código não posso compartilhar mais é mais ou menos assim.

Tenho um formulário com o input file e um input button no click do Button o JS chama uma função que pega os `values` do `form` e faz um `array(JSON)`, então faz o Ajax com o PHP para inserção no banco.

Só que o *array* quando esta no PHO não vem o nome da imagem. Blz então fiz direto no PHP assim: `$img = $_FILES["arquivo"]["name"];` e ele também retorna vazia a variável. Tudo esta correto o `form` com o *enctype*, mais de qualquer forma não funciona.

Html:

```
<form action="?pagina=cadastroEmpresas" method="POST" id="formEmpresa" name="formEmpresa" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input value="Salvar" id="btnSalvarForm" style="padding: 5px; font-size: 14px; margin-left: -13px;" type="button">
<label for="arquivo">Logo:</label> <input name="arquivo" id="arquivo" value="" type="file" />
```

JS:

```
$( "#btnSalvarForm" ).on("click", function() {
    inserirEmpresa();
});
function inserirEmpresa(){
    campos = pegarCampos( "formEmpresa" );
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        data : {dados:JSON.stringify(campos)},
        url : "php/buscaEmpresasBD.php?escolha=7",
        success : function(resposta){
            alert(resposta);
            $("#divCamposForm").css("display", "none");
        }//fim success      
    });//fim ajax
}
```

PHP:

```
function inserirEmpresa(){
        global $cnx;
        //echo $_POST['dados'];
        $dados = json_decode($_POST['dados'], TRUE);
        //echo $dados["txtNomeFantasiaEmpresa"];
        $target_dir = "galeria/";
        //$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["arquivo"]["name"]);
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["arquivo"]["name"]);
        echo "$target_file";
}
```

Comment: Assim sem dar mais dados ou mostrar o código fica difícil ajudar.

Comment: Se tudo está correto o problema deve ser outra coisa, coloque o código que você tem.

Comment: O `input[type=file]` submete apenas o array de bytes que representa o arquivo físico local. Se você quer submeter o nome do arquivo você precisa atribuir por `JavaScript` a outro `input` o nome do arquivo selecionado apresentado no `input[typr=file]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você estiver usando `ajax`, arquivo não faz upload por `ajax`. Mas tem uns métodos que se faz que dá certo.

Algumas perguntas sobre isso:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447435/ajax-upload-image 
[Fazer upload de arquivo com AJAX](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9704/fazer-upload-de-arquivo-com-ajax)

Mas caso queira pegar o **nome** (não o arquivo) - do arquivo por JS (jQuery) faz assim:

```
$('.file').on('change', function(){

    // Pega o Nome do Arquivo
    var fileName = $('input[type="file"]')[0].files[0].name;

    // Coloca num campo Hidden com ID #file-name
    $('#file-name').val(fileName);

});
```

Comment: entao mesmo usando esse seu codigo acima ele fala que arquivo é indefinido!

Comment: Mas você editou o código de acordo com o seu ? Eu coloquei uma class `.file` no `onchange`. Seu `input file` está com uma class chamada `file` ?

Comment: Ufaa! Agora sim ! Valeu Diego !! Salvo meu serviço kkk