# Qual Forma Acesso FTP Da XPG Via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, ftp

Têm como acessar minha conta gratuita no servidor de hospedagem XPG, por intermédio de Javascript?

Desejo saber se é possivel fazer uma conexão com apenas Javascript com um servidor FTP(ftp://ftp.xpg.com.br), para "Enviar" arquivos.

> Preciso de alguma maneira ao selecionar o arquivo local ja fazer o login no FTP(ftp://ftp.xpg.com.br) em seguida fazer *"upload"*.

Sei que dá, com os avanços da **ECMAScript, APIs, DOM** ja se faz algumas maravilhas que antigamente não era possível, do tipo acessar arquivos do Computador.

Felizmente, isso não acontece mais, graças à API FileSystem. Com a API FileSystem, um aplicativo da web pode criar, ler, navegar e gravar em uma seção em sandbox do sistema de arquivos local do usuário.

**Node.js** é uma plataforma para desenvolvimento de aplicações server-side baseadas em rede utilizando JavaScript e o V8 JavaScript Engine, ou seja, com Node.js podemos criar uma variedade de aplicações Web utilizando apenas código em JavaScript.

Mas o meu conhecimento sobre assunto Javascript e *Bibliotecas* é particularmente razoável. Isso é uma maneira educada de dizer não sei por onde começar.

Encontrei navegando dentro SOpt - [Fazer upload de arquivo com AJAX](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9704/fazer-upload-de-arquivo-com-ajax) isto é uma citação sobre parte do assunto aqui mencionado "Envio de arquivos"

Ainda resta saber como **logar na conta**.

Comment: Nunca tentei, mas acho que com ajax pode ser possível. Veja que tem um trecho que diz _"(including file and ftp)"_ em [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pesquisando, encontrei uma API javascript para tal:
http://www.ftpjs.xyz/.

Com a mesma é possível enviar arquivos do input:

```
<script src="http://ftpjs.xyz/ftp.js"></script>

<input type=file onchange="Ftp.upload('access_token', this.files)"/>
```

O próprio site gera essa token baseado nos dados de conexão que você informa.

Achei bem simples e legal apesar de ser apenas upload!

---

Segue então o código para saberem se é viável ou não utilizar:

```
// Script from http://FTPJS.XYZ
// Copyright 2016 FTPJS.XYZ, DO NOT REMOVE THIS COPYRIGHT NOTICE
var Ftp = {
    createCORSRequest: function (method, url) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
            // Check if the XMLHttpRequest object has a "withCredentials" property.
            // "withCredentials" only exists on XMLHTTPRequest2 objects.
            xhr.open(method, url, true);
        } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
            // Otherwise, check if XDomainRequest.
            // XDomainRequest only exists in IE, and is IE's way of making CORS requests.
            xhr = new XDomainRequest();
            xhr.open(method, url);
        } else {
            // Otherwise, CORS is not supported by the browser.
            xhr = null;
        }
        return xhr;
    },
    upload: function(token, files) {
        var file = files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.addEventListener("load",
            function() {
                var base64 = this.result;               
                var xhr = Ftp.createCORSRequest('POST', "http://www.ftpjs.xyz/upload.aspx");
                if (!xhr) {
                    throw new Error('CORS not supported');
                }
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                        Ftp.callback(file);
                    }
                };
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xhr.send("token=" + token + "&data=" + encodeURIComponent(base64) + "&file=" + file.name);
            },
            false);
    },
    callback: function(){}
};
```

Comment: Não sei se vocês perceberam, mas isso não faz **conexão ao FTP** usando JavaScript - eu acho muito pouco provável que isso seja possível (falando em client-side, no Node é provável que exista algo). Isso é apenas uma lib que faz requisições para um servidor e lá que são feitas as requisições pro FTP. Logo, tomem cuidado, porque vocês não sabem se eles não estão ou não salvando as credenciais do seu servidor FTP em algum lugar. Não estou duvidando da boa vontade da parte dos desenvolvedores da lib, mas me pareceu que vocês não perceberam isso, então achei melhor avisá-los ***=)***.

Comment: Tem uma página ASPX no backend.