# Enviar arquivos de upload com validação Jquery e Modal Bootstrap

Tags: jquery

COlegas.

Tenho um site onde o formulário é validado com Jquery através de um modal Bootstrap e estando tudo OK a mensagem é enviada. Porém incluímos um campo **file** para envios de arquivos via upload. O problema que estamos encontrando, é que o arquivo não vai para a página de validação de envio:

```
<form role="form" class="contact-form" id="contact-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div id="final" class="form-group invisivel radio">
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Arquivo">Arquivo:</label>
    <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-upload fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      <input name="Arquivo" class="form-control" type="file" placeholder="Envie arquivo">
    </div>
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Arquivos suportados: PDF, .doc e .docx</small>
 </div>     
</div>
```

JQUery

```
<script> 
           $('form').submit(function () { 
function (d) { 
               $.post("enviar.php", $(".contact-form").serialize(), function(d) {
                    $('#success').html(d);
                    $('#myModal').find(".modal-body").html(d); 
                    $('#myModal').modal('show'); 
                }); 
               return false; 
           }); 
          </script>
```

PHP

```
echo $_FILES['Arquivo']['name'];
```

Como eu faria aproveitando o código jquery para validação com Modal Bootstrap?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Fazer upload de arquivo com AJAX](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9704/fazer-upload-de-arquivo-com-ajax)

Comment: Relacionada: [Upload não chega ao PHP via AJAX com função .serialize()](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/176033)

Comment: Desculpem a ignorância, mas como eu faria para aplicar dentro do modal Bootstrap? O código que passei funciona, só não envia arquivos de upload.

Comment: E os links que passei não resolvem o problema do upload? Acedito que sim.

Comment: Não conheço muito jquery e gostaria de incorporar a solução do link dentro do que já temos, pois a nossa validação usa o modal do Bootstrap. Temos outros campos textos que funcionam e o código que você passou parece que é focado em apenas uploads. Apesar de terem quase o mesmo título, mas são situações diferentes.