# Enviar FILE do javascript ao php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tenho lido muita coisa à respeito do assunto e estou ficando mais confuso.

Tenho o form abaixo:

```
<div class="plano">

  <h1 class="titulos">Cadastro de Plano</h1>

  <form method="post" class="planoCadastrar">

    <input type="text" name="nomePlano" id="nomePlano" class="typeTextMedio" placeholder="Nome"  required /><br /><br />

    <textarea placeholder="Descrição" class="textarea" name="descricao" id="descricao" cols="93" rows="15" required></textarea><br /> <br />

    <div id="multiple_upload">
        <input type="hidden" id="arquivos" name="arquivos" onChange="alert(this.value)" />
        <input type="file" multiple id="fotos"  name="fotos[]" />
        <div id="message">Selecionar fotos</div> 
        <div id="lista"></div>
    </div>          

    <img class="spinner" src="../_img/_bannerImgs/spinner.gif" />          
    <input type="submit" class="btnAcesso" value="Enviar" />

    <label class="resposta"></label>

  </form><br /><br />

  <script> 
    $('.elevate-image').ezPlus({
        zoomType: 'inner',
        cursor: 'crosshair'     
    });
  </script>  

</div>
```

Nele eu tenho um campo `FILE` para envio de **arquivos**.

Estou usando `$.post()` do **jQuery** para enviar esse **formulário** para uma página **php** sem `refresh`.

Tudo vai bem e consigo pegar no **php** mas o campo `FILE` não vai.

Estou tentando meio que uma **gabiarra** mas mesmo assim tive que parar para pedir ajuda.

O jQuery:

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $("div.conteudo div.plano form.planoCadastrar").on("submit", function() {

        var nomePlano = $("form.planoCadastrar input[type=text]#nomePlano").val();
        var descricao = $("form.planoCadastrar textarea#descricao").val();
        var arquivos  = $("form.planoCadastrar input[type=hidden]#arquivos").val();
        var fotosPost = $("form.planoCadastrar input[type=file]")[0].files;

        fotos = new Array();
             for (var i=0; i < fotosPost.length; i++) { 

                 fotos[i]["name"]     = fotosPost[i].name
                 fotos[i]["type"]     = fotosPost[i].type
                 fotos[i]["size"]     = fotosPost[i].size
                 fotos[i]["tmp_name"] = fotosPost[i].tmp_name

             }

             return false;

        if ( nomePlano == "" || 
             descricao == "") {

            alert("Algum campo está vazio!");

        } 


         $("div.conteudo div.plano form.planoCadastrar input[type=submit].btnAcesso").css('display', 'none');
         $("div.conteudo div.plano form.planoCadastrar img").css('display', 'block');

         $.post ("../_requeridos/cadastraPlano.php", {

             nomePlano   : nomePlano,
             descricao   : descricao,
             arquivos    : arquivos,
             fotos       : fotos

         }, function(retorno){

             $("div.conteudo div.plano form.planoCadastrar input[type=submit].btnAcesso").css('display', 'block');
             $("div.conteudo div.plano form.planoCadastrar img").css('display', 'none');

              if (retorno == 1) {
                resposta = "Plano cadastrado com sucesso!"; 
              } else {
                resposta = "Erro no cadastro do Plano";
              }
             $(".resposta").css("display", "block");
             $(".resposta").html(resposta);     

           }
          );

          return false;

    });

});
```

Tentei fazer a tal **gabiarra** com o código abaixo:

```
     for (var i=0; i < fotosPost.length; i++) { 

         fotos[i]["name"]     = fotosPost[i].name
         fotos[i]["type"]     = fotosPost[i].type
         fotos[i]["size"]     = fotosPost[i].size
         fotos[i]["tmp_name"] = fotosPost[i].tmp_name

     }
```

Mas quando chego no

```
         fotos[i]["tmp_name"] = fotosPost[i].tmp_name
```

Não consigo pegar o valor.

Será que existe um **recurso** para isso?

Ou terei mesmo que submeter o **formulário**.

A ideia é pegar o `array` do `FILE` e criar um `array` `javascript`, enviar para o **php** e ***converter*** novamente em array **php** para ver se consigo fazer o **upload** do **arquivo**.

Comment: Acho que esses posts podem te ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9704/fazer-upload-de-arquivo-com-ajax https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899384/uploading-both-data-and-files-in-one-form-using-ajax

Comment: Qual parte? Estou tendo problemas quando precisa enviar mais que uma imagem pois só lista uma