# Ajax e PHP para upload de imagens + cadastro de informações

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estou me batendo desde ontem com um upload de imagens em AJAX. Vou publicar os avanços que tive em estudo e as dificuldades que ainda tenho caso alguém consiga me auxiliar :)

Meu script como sempre fiz (sem imagens) era, basicamente, o formulário

```
<form id="cadastrar-evento" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <label>Título</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Título do Evento" name="titulo">

    <label>Descrição</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Descrição do Evento" name="descricao" id="descricao-evento" maxlength="240"></textarea>

    <hr>

    <label>Fotos</label>

    <input id="selecao-arquivo1" type="file" name="imagem1">
    <input id="selecao-arquivo2" type="file" name="imagem2">
    <input id="selecao-arquivo3" type="file" name="imagem3">

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Cadastrar Evento" id="botao">
```

Meu Ajax

```
//Cadastrar
$('form#cadastrar-evento').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this);

    //(...) Validações

    var valores = form.serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'dados/cadastro-evento.php',
        data : valores,
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(data){
            if(data.status == 1){
                alert(data.msg);
                window.location.href="index.php?pg=eventos";
            }else{
                alert(data.msg);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Mas aí, pesquisando, verifiquei precisava trocar o serialize pelo método formData e fiz isso:

```
//Cadastrar
$('form#cadastrar-evento').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

   var form = $(this);

   //(...) Validações

   valores = new FormData(form);
    //var valores = form.serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'dados/cadastro-evento.php',
        data: valores,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false, 
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            if(data.status == 1){
                alert(data.msg);
                window.location.href="index.php?pg=eventos";
            }else{
                alert(data.msg);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Porém meu console apresenta como se o formData não tivesse definido?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No PHP eu retorno um jSON, mas pelo que entendi também não posso utilizar mais o retorno dessa forma. Ou posso?

```
if($sqlInsereEvento){
    $retorno = array("status" => 1, "msg" => "Evento cadastrado com sucesso!");
    echo json_encode($retorno);
    exit;
}else{
    $retorno = array("status" => 0, "msg" => "Ocorreu algum erro ao cadastrar este evento, tente novamente.");
    echo json_encode($retorno);
    exit;
}
```

Agradeço desde já se alguém conseguir elucidar essas dúvidas.

**UPDATE**

Agora não aparecem erros no JS, essa é minha última versão:

```
    (...)
    valores = new FormData(form);
    //var valores = form.serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'dados/cadastro-evento.php',
        data: {valores},
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false, 
        dataType : 'json', //Sem o JSON não recebo retorno do PHP. Recebo Undefined.
        success : function(data){
            if(data.status == 1){
                alert(data.msg);
                window.location.href="index.php?pg=eventos";
            }else{
                alert(data.msg);
            }
        }
    });
```

Mas aparentemente **os valores não chegam no meu PHP**. Tentei imprimir os posts e ele só me retorna "oi" no alert.

```
//(...)

$titulo      = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['titulo']);
$descricao   = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['descricao']);

//Verifica Campos Vazios caso js esteja com problemas
if(empty($titulo) || empty($descricao)){
    $retorno = array("status" => 0, "msg" => "oi $titulo $descricao");
    echo json_encode($retorno);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: acredito que o seu problema esteja que no post do ajax, você diz que está enviando um dado json, e não está, remova o datatype

Comment: De uma olhada aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9704/fazer-upload-de-arquivo-com-ajax

Comment: @AndersonHenrique aí meu PHP retorna "undefined" pro Ajax e cai naquele último problema que eu mencionei ali. Não tenho certeza como posso retornar os erros pro js :/

Comment: @AndersonHenrique Ah sim, já vi essa questão. Mas sigo com dificuldade de implementar. Nesse arquivo ali ele considera somente envio de imagem (pelo que entendi)

Comment: tenta assim: data:{valores}

Comment: @JorgeMatheus hummm, parou de retornar erro no console. Agora o js apresenta um alert vazio. Vou fazer uns testes no meu PHP e confirmo. Mas talvez tenha resolvido :)

Comment: Então, você tem que mandar  um objeto no data, por isso tem que ter as {}. Se for isso, eu respondo e você marca como correto.

Comment: @AryanaValcanaia Acredito que o problema esteja no php, vamos lá, siga os passos, indique a posição do new Form, sei que está pegando o evento por id mas só por precaução, data = new Form($('form#cadastrar-evento')[0]), remova o datatype: json, para que o ajax use o metodo correto automaticamente, e se puder edite e coloque o seu php recebendo o POST

Comment: @AndersonHenrique acho que o js mesmo :/

Comment: @JorgeMatheus o problema é no ajax que não envia as infos pro PHP. se eu refazer o ajax usando o serialize() ele passa todas as infos (exceto $_FILES)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajustei o js e resolvido :)

HTML

```
<form id="cadastrar-evento" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   <label>Título</label>
   <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Título do Evento" name="titulo">

   <label>Descrição</label>
   <textarea class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Descrição do Evento" name="descricao" id="descricao-evento" maxlength="240"></textarea>

   <hr>

   <label>Fotos</label>

   <input id="selecao-arquivo1" type="file" name="imagem1">
   <input id="selecao-arquivo2" type="file" name="imagem2">
   <input id="selecao-arquivo3" type="file" name="imagem3">

   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Cadastrar Evento" id="botao">

</form>
```

Ajax

```
$("form#cadastrar-evento").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: "dados/cadastro-evento.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
        dataType : 'json',
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.msg);
        }
    });
});
```

PHP capturo post e files e manipulo normal de acordo com o que eu quiser

```
//Textos
$titulo      = $_POST['titulo'];
$descricao   = $_POST['descricao'];

//Imagens
$imagem1     = $_FILES['imagem1']['name'];
$imagem2     = $_FILES['imagem2']['name'];
$imagem3     = $_FILES['imagem3']['name'];

//Exemplo de retorno
//Verifica Campos Vazios caso js esteja com problemas
if(empty($titulo) || empty($descricao)){
    $retorno = array("status" => 0, "msg" => "Você precisa preencher os campos obrigatórios.");
    echo json_encode($retorno);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: posta a resposta completa!!

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Achei que em conjunto ao enunciado havia ficado claro. Resposta editada.

Comment: Assim sua resposta ficou melhor de entender!!