# Como fazer upload usando PHP de imagem em link BLOB?

Tags: php, upload, link, blob

Estou fazendo uso de um projeto do GitHub (xkeshi/image-compressor) que comprime imagens usando JavaScript. Ele gera um download do arquivo comprimido com o seguinte link por exemplo `blob:http://localhost/945f825f-054a-4170-9d79-ac1dba593d23`

Note que o URL começa com `blob:`

Como fazer upload com PHP do arquivo para o servidor, já que aparentemente o arquivo está local?

## Dados:

Projeto do GitHub que originou pergunta: https://github.com/xkeshi/image-compressor

#### O que eu já tentei

```
<?php
//Arquivo que desejo fazer upload blob:http://localhost/945f825f-054a-4170-9d79-ac1dba593d23
$url = 'blob:http://localhost/945f825f-054a-4170-9d79-ac1dba593d23';
$img = '/p/a.jpg';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
?>
```

#### Erro que apresenta

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(blob:http://localhost/945f825f-054a-4170-9d79-ac1dba593d23): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\1\a\b\docs\p.php on line 5

> Warning: file_put_contents(/p/a.jpg): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\1\a\b\docs\p.php on line 5

Comment: o teu problema está no caminho da imagem que forneces como parâmetro

Comment: Considere adicionar o trecho do código que você esta usando/instanciando a biblioteca. Fica difícil imaginar como você obteve um **objectURL** uma vez que a biblioteca só retorna `File` ou `Blob`

Comment: Bom, agora entendi de onde você tirou este **objectURL**...você tirou isto da página [DEMO](https://xkeshi.github.io/image-compressor/). Note que o repositório não é publico, o mantenedor usa Vue e o que ele faz é usar a biblioteca para gerar o `Blob()` e usa `URL.createObjectURL()` para gerar este link e atribuir a um elemento `<a>` com o atributo `download`. Você deveria considerar a resposta que lhe foi apresentada, é a maneira mais recomendada de fazer o upload do objeto que a biblioteca lhe retorna.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O [protocolo `blob`](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#DefinitionOfScheme) ou [Object-URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL#Parameters) somente podem ser gerados pelo `browser` e essas `URL's` só podem ser acessadas/gerenciados na mesma instância/sessão, do `browser`, que os gerou.

Logo, fica evidente que o PHP não tem acesso a `URL` criada.

Por outro lado, você pode enviar o arquivo criado pela biblioteca `xkeshi/image-compressor` via `ajax` (`XMLHttpRequest`).

Veja o exemplo no [manual](https://github.com/xkeshi/image-compressor#example):

```
new ImageCompressor(file, {
    quality: .6,
    success(result) {
        const formData = new FormData();

        formData.append('file', result, result.name);

        // Envia a imagem comprimida ao servidor usando XMLHttpRequest.
        axios.post('/path/to/upload', formData).then(() => {
            console.log('Upload success');
        });
    },
    error(e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    },
});
```

Feito isso, basta você salvar o arquivo enviado no PHP, de forma similar ao salvar um upload normal.

[Fazer upload de arquivo com AJAX](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9712/5007)

[POST method uploads](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Comment: Me corrija se eu estiver errado más, neste exemplo o arquivo esta vindo de um `<input type="file">` que é do sistema de arquivos do usuário e não de um **blob**?

Comment: Eu vou me corrigir aqui: sua resposta esta correta, por curiosidade eu testei a biblioteca e ela retorna apenas `File` ou `Blob` não consigo imaginar como ele obteve um **objectURL**

Comment: @LauroMoraes é o que a [biblioteca trabalha internamente](https://github.com/xkeshi/image-compressor/blob/master/src/index.js#L73). É isso que, em sua maioria, as bibliotecas fazem/são. Elas encapsulam e facilitam funcionalidades nativas, provendo uma interfáce/API mais amigável ao desenvolvedor.

Comment: @LauroMoraes minha vez de me corrigir, achei que você era o autor da pergunta. Se você quiser baixar o arquivo comprimido, pode-se utilizar a `promise` retornada, obter a URL gerada e iniciar o download. Acredito que este tenha sido o ponto de partida do autor da pergunta.

Comment: Mas não é isso que é retornada para o usuário. O **objectURL** é usado internamente para abastecer uma imagem e um `canvas` posteriormente (dentro da cadeia de resultados da promises) extrai o **dataURI** deste `canvas` converte em **buffer** e abastece um `Blob()`. Este sim por sua vez é o que é devolvido como resultado. Veja nas linhas [231 -> 235](https://github.com/xkeshi/image-compressor/blob/master/src/index.js#L231,L235)

Comment: @LauroMoraes é possível, também, que o autor tenha debugado o código para validar aonde a imagem é criada.

Comment: É exatamente por isso que não consigo imaginar de onde ele obteve um **objectURL**...talvez tenha sido "debugando" mesmo.

Comment: Se observarem o projeto do GitHub, tem como objetivo a compressão de imagens, ao selecionar uma imagem por um input do tipo file, é feita a compressão do arquivo onde será possível baixar a imagem pelo link blob que eu mencionei. Como eu disse, tudo isso acontece no navegador, não há arquivo físico, apenas um botão de download que direciona ao link.

Comment: @RORSCHACH acredito que a pergunta no ar seja, o código proposto resolveu seu problema?