# React e Web API - Como submeter form com arquivos

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api, react

Estou utilizando React para desenvolvimento do front e c# Web API para back.

Estou tentando submeter um form que possui um input file, na API criei uma ViewModel para receber esses dados. Antes de submeter, coloco os dados do form em um `FormData`, que está sendo preenchido corretamente - verifiquei no console - porém na API o objeto recebe sempre os valores vazios.

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('IdMobileOperator', this.state.IdMobileOperator)
data.append('IdProductType', this.state.IdProductType)
data.append('TradeInDate', this.state.TradeInDate)
data.append('File', this.state.files)

$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: 'POST',
  data: { simCards: data },
  processData: false,
  success: function (response) {
    //do something
  }.bind(this),
  error: function (response) {
    //do something else
  }
});
```

Na API, a action que recebe os dados é a seguinte:

```
[Route("Api/SimCard/Import")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ImportSimCard([FromBody]SimCardImportViewModel simCards)
{
   //do something
}
```

Da forma que está, a action é encontrada pela requisição, porém o objeto `simCards` tem todas as propriedades sem valor - o quando numérico, null quando objeto, etc.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9704/fazer-upload-de-arquivo-com-ajax um exemplo

Comment: Não entendi qual parte da sua pergunta está relacionada ao react

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira citei o React a principio para contextualizar e também por achar que poderia ser algo relacionado a ele, mas depois desta tarde pesquisando, percebi que não e consegui chegar numa resposta usando formData. De qualquer forma obrigado, e assim que me sobrar um tempinho eu volto para atualizar a pergunta.