# Como pegar o um arquivo no PHP passado pelo $.ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estou com um problema não sei se é ao enviar no $.ajax ou em pegar com PHP.

Não está chegando o `$_FILES` normal do outro lado, chega como `'caminhofoto' => string 'C:\fakepath\1.jpg' (length=17)`, dei `var_dump($_POST)`, porém ao tentar pegar o caminho e mover para o diretório ele so monta o caminho mais não pega o arquivo.

Meu JS:

```js
var caminhofoto = $("input[name='caminhofoto']").val();

        $.ajax({
                url: '/add-data.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    caminhofoto: caminhofoto
                }
            }).done(function (data) {
            
                console.log("Sucesso: " + data);
           
            });
```

E no PHP:

```
$img = "imgs/";
$caminhofoto = $img . basename($_FILES['caminhofoto']['name']);
$imgFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($caminhofoto, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

$uploaddir = '/fotos/';
$obj->setPath($uploaddir . $caminhofoto );
```

Só que está gravando no banco somente o caminho sem o arquivo, parece que como está indo como fakepath ele não está conseguindo pegar.

Comment: O upload via ajax esta incorreto, você deve fazer como explicado nesta resposta [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9712/3774](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9712/3774)

Comment: No caso eu não posso usar submit para enviar o formulário, pois preciso pegar os dados manuais de cada input,
nesse caso o ` var formData = new FormData(this);` não vai funcionar.

Comment: Por que não vai funcionar?

Comment: Porque minha função e se o usuário clicar no botão do tipo button, ela pega os dados um a um e envia para o PHP. Ao invés de dar submit no form.

Comment: Você pode usar algo do tipo  `var formData = new FormData();`,  `formData.append('foto', $("input[name='caminhofoto']").prop('files')[0] );` ao invés de `var formData = new FormData(this);`

Comment: Bacana deu certo.
Obrigado,
Coloca como resposta que eu marco como resolvido @IcaroMartins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conversamos pelos comentários da pergunta e foi constatado que o problema estava ocorrendo por causa da forma como o valor estava sendo enviado pelo `ajax`.

Utilizando o [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) para enviar o arquivo ele iria conseguir chegar ao objetivo como mostrado no exemplo abaixo.

```
var formData = new FormData(),
    $inputFoto = $("input[name='caminhofoto']");

 formData.append('foto', $inputFoto.prop('files')[0] );

 $.ajax({
     url: '/add-data.php',
     type: 'POST',
     data: formData,
     success: function(data) {
         alert(data)
     },
     cache: false,
     contentType: false,
     processData: false,
});
```

*Outra resposta que vale apena olhar por [Gabriel Gartz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9712/3774)*