# Carregar conteúdo externo com AJAX para variável global JavaScript

Tags: ajax, variáveis

Estou carregando alguns dados de um arquivo externo (`.txt`) local utilizando *AJAX*, gostaria de saber como posso armazenar estes dados em uma variavel global para manipulação dos dados, pois preciso separar algumas informações e alocar em tabelas.
OBS: esta pagina vai ser executada localmente.

Segue abaixo o codigo que estou utilizando.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">                               
        var temp;
        temp = 100;
        var intervalo = window.setInterval(altura, temp);
        function altura()
          {
            var divh = document.getElementById("DataText").offsetHeight; 
            window.scrollBy(0,divh)                                        
          };

        $(function()
          {
            setTime();
            function setTime()
            {
              $('#DataText').load("https://textuploader.com/151x2");
              setTimeout(setTime, temp);                         
            }
          });                
      </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
        <th>Cabeçalho</th>
        <th>Outro Cabeçalho</th>
        <th>Outro Cabeçalho</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>linha 1, célula 1</td>
        <td>linha 1, célula 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>linha 2, célula 1</td>
        <td>linha 2, célula 2</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
   <div id="DataText" style="width: 200px; font-size: 10px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que você pode utilizar o [`$.get`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/#jQuery-get-url-data-success-dataType), isso se o arquivo estiver no servidor. 
Caso `local` você esteja se referindo ao computador de quem esta acessando a pagina você terá que utilizar um outro metodo, [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/362876/3774) mostra como fazer para carregar os dados de um arquivo sem enviar para o servidor.
<sub>[Nota]: Na resposta o `FileReader` esta usando `readAsDataURL` você teria que usar `readAsText`.</sub>

Exemplo `$.get`

```
$.get( "registro0.txt", funcaoCallback);

function funcaoCallback( conteudo ) {
     /// Callback, chamada após o $.get pegar o
     ///  conteudo do arquivo aqui dentro voce
     ///  pode tratar o conteudo do arquivo

     console.log(conteudo);

     /// colocando os dados no elemento de id='DataText'
     $('#DataText').text( conteudo );

}
```

---

Em um comentario você disse que estava dando erro `XML Parser:....`
voce pode tentar colocar como ultimo parametro da chamada `'text'` ficando assim:

```
$.get( "registro0.txt", funcaoCallback, 'text');
```

Comment: sim, é um arquivo local no meu computador, a função esta funcionando, consigo exibir o log na div, o problema é que preciso manipular os dados antes de exibir eles, tipo criar um filtro do que vai ser exibido, esta pagina vai ser rodada localmente.

Comment: Então apos o `$.get` pegar os dados ele chama uma função sua, nessa função você pode tratar os dados. No exemplo a minha função esta apenas chamando o `console.log`

Comment: consegui resolver a questão do erro adicionando a referencia "plain" ao cabeçalho,, porem o ainda não obtive resultado na leitura do arquivo, agora estou obtendo erro que o $ não foi declarado.